# How to pass a <td></td> value to a php variable?

Tags: php, html

I'm currently working on a library system and I encountered a problem of mine which I've encoutered for the first time. When I displayed all the books that are currently in the library, I loop them to tables  using php. Now, I want to pass the ISBN value of a current column to a variable and maybe use it to run a query to display information of a certain book. Below is the div part of my code.

```
    <div class="search-result">
        <table cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>ISBN</th>
                <th>BOOK TITLE</th>
                <th class="authorName">AUTHOR NAME</th>
                <th>SERIES</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <?php
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                ?>
                    <td><?php echo $row['ISBN'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Title'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Author'] ?></td>  
                    <td><?php echo $row['Series'] ?></td>
                    <td><a class="borrow-button" href="view.php">BORROW</a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I've not tried anyting solution because I can't find on the internet what I've been looking for. I hope someone can help me

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, but I _assume_ you want to have something clickable on the client side to show _additional_ information? For that you need client side logic, so javascript. You could wrap the table into a form and create submit buttons for those ISDN fields, but that leads to a bad UX. Instead use client side logic and make an AJAX request to fetch the additional information. You will find many examples for that on the internet.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, this is for the client side and all the rows have a BORROW button at the end. I can't think of what to do when a user clicks the borrow button, I want to get its ISBN value from the row then pass it into a PHP variable then use it to pass it into a query.

Comment: @jericviernes30 I actually answered to how to pass it: either use a php form and submit that, or use client side logic (javascript) to make an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wish to display detail of the book when  someone clicks ISBN. Here is what you can do

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
?>
                
/* 
you can use a link tag in the ISBN column and
then in "viewdetail.php or whatever you wish to call it 
and can then search database using ISBN number and display 
result."
*/
<td>
    <a href="viewdetail.php?isbn=<?php echo $row['ISBN'] ?>"><?php echo $row['ISBN'] ?></a>
</td>
<td><?php echo $row['Title'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Author'] ?></td>  
<td><?php echo $row['Series'] ?></td>
<td><a class="borrow-button" href="view.php">BORROW</a></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Otherwise you will have to use javascript AJAX to fetch the result.